# How can I unload video when it has finished playing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to unload a video when it has finished playing. No luck so far. Can anyone help please? [**JSFIDDLE example here**](https://jsfiddle.net/1b0Lbdnh/13/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#video').on('ended',function(){
      $('#video').get(0).unload();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @GCyrillus, but this does not seem to work. Plus it disables the ability to toggle the video on/off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have included the solution at jsfiddle and in this snippet below.  Note that I used .toggle() instead of .unload(), since .unload() is meant to be fired on window event :

https://jsfiddle.net/firelite/h4aqkgo1/

```js
$('#videoButton').on('click', function() {
  var videoDiv = $('#videoDiv').toggle();

  if (videoDiv.is(':visible')) {
    $('#video').get(0).load();
    $('#video').get(0).play();
  } else {
    $('#video').get(0).pause();
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#video').on('ended', function() {
    $('#video').get(0).pause();
    $('#videoDiv').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#videoDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  position: relative;
}
#videoBlock,
#videoMessage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.videoClick {
  text-align: center
}
.videoClick a {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.25);
  font-size: 1.7em;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="videoButton">Toggle video</button>
<div id="videoDiv" style="display:none">
  <div id="videoBlock">
    <video preload="preload" id="video">
      <source src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/054833/files/093143183/fotel-photography-course-tour-workshop-video-4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so very very much, @Transattic!! It works great!! Kept trying but could not find the solution myself or online. What a relief that you've helped me. Thanks again!

Comment: @Eddy, I'm glad this was what you were looking for!  Enjoy your Thanksgiving weekend :)

Comment: could you please take a look here, and see if you notice any obviously wrong? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40805233/video-not-showing-in-safari-but-only-does-show-after-a-bit-of-scrolling