# Video not showing in safari, but only does show after a bit of scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a video that, while using Safari, is not responding the way it should. It does load because I can hear the sound of the video, but I can only see the video after I've scrolled a bit. In other words: the video is not visible till i scroll the browser window.  [**Please Check here**](http://www.photographycoursetour.com) and click on a red bag.

This is the code I have used:

```js
$('#video-togglebutton').on('click', function() {
  var videoDiv = $('#videoDiv').toggle();

  if (videoDiv.is(':visible')) {
    $('#video').get(0).load();
    $('#video').get(0).play();
  } else {
    $('#video').get(0).pause();
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#video').on('ended', function() {
    $('#video').get(0).pause();
    $('#videoDiv').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#videoDiv {
            display:none;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, 0);
            height: 35vw;
            position: relative;
            text-align:center;
            
          }
          
          #videoBlock{
            width:60vw;
            height: 35vw;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, 0);
            
          }
          
          .videoClick {
            text-align: center;
          }
          
          .videoClick a {
            color: white;
            font-size: 1.7em;
            cursor: pointer;
            cursor: hand
          }
          
          
          video {
            background-image: url("{{ 'fotel-photography-loading-3.svg' | url_asset }}");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100px 100px;
            background-position: center;
            margin-top:-34px;
            width:100%;           
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="video-togglebutton">Toggle video</button>
<div id="videoDiv" style="display:none">
  <div id="videoBlock">
    <video preload="preload" id="video">
      <source src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/054833/files/093143183/fotel-photography-course-tour-workshop-video-4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I considered a hack, using this extra code below into the if statement above, but I does not work.

```
    if(video.readyState == 4){
      $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop()+1);
      $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop()-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works (bit of a hack):

```
/*makes window scroll down and up again one pixel, after page is loaded*/  
$(window).load(function(){
   $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop()+1);
   $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop()-1); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `width: 100%` the the video element `#video` and you'll have it with tha same width as the body:

```
#video {
  width:100%;
}
```

```js
$('#video-togglebutton').on('click', function() {
  var videoDiv = $('#videoDiv').toggle();

  if (videoDiv.is(':visible')) {
    $('#video').get(0).load();
    $('#video').get(0).play();
  } else {
    $('#video').get(0).pause();
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#video').on('ended', function() {
    $('#video').get(0).pause();
    $('#videoDiv').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#videoDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  position: relative;
}
#videoBlock,
#videoMessage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#video {
  width:100%;
}

.videoClick {
  text-align: center
}
.videoClick a {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.25);
  font-size: 1.7em;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand
}

video {
 background-image: url("{{ 'fotel-photography-loading-3.svg' | url_asset }}");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100px 100px;
 background-position: center;
 margin-top:-34px;
 width:100%;           
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="video-togglebutton">Toggle video</button>
<div id="videoDiv" style="display:none">
  <div id="videoBlock">
    <video preload="preload" id="video">
      <source src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/054833/files/093143183/fotel-photography-course-tour-workshop-video-4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Christos Lytras. However, this makes no difference. I have edited the code in my question.